# Problem with RadioGroup.ControlCount in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, radio-button, delphi-2010

I'd like to set RadioButton properties in runtime in procedure InitRadioGroup(). 
It fails because RadioGroup.ControlCount is 0, although there are 3 RadioButtons in RadioGroup.

What is wrong in D2010 RadioGroup? 
Same code works fine in Delphi 2007.

```
procedure InitRadioGroup(RadioGroup: TRadioGroup);
var
  i: integer;
  RadioButton: TRadioButton;
begin
  for i := 0 to RadioGroup.ControlCount - 1 do
  begin
    RadioButton := (RadioGroup.Controls[i] as TRadioButton);

    RadioButton.ParentColor := False;
    RadioButton.ParentFont  := False;
    RadioButton.Font.Style  := [];
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the RadioGroup is not visible when your procedure is called. So the RadioButtons may not be created then.

A call to `RadioGroup.HandleNeeded` should fix this for you.

Comment: You are right. I initialize many RadioGroups before I show tabsheet where Radiogroups are.

Comment: I added RadioGroup.HandleNeeded and it is OK now. Thank you.