# Accessing Radiogroup Buttons throws exception

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

This is a test application I made to reproduce the issue:

[image]

Please have a look at the following test code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(radioGroup1.Items[0]);
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(radioGroup1.Buttons[0].Enabled));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(radioGroup1.Items[0]);
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(radioGroup1.Buttons[0].Enabled)); //<- Fails!!!
end;
```

The first ShowMessage in FormCreate is shown, and displays the correct text (Item1).

The second code line in FormCreate throws an exception, that index is out of bounds.

If I run the same code in a button click event as shown in the code as well (after the form has loaded) everything works fine.

**Question 1:** 
It appears that the buttons have not been loaded at the time the second code line is executed in FormCreate.
Why is this the case, when the items themself appear to be loaded already?

**Question 2:** 
I noticed the issue when upgrading an existing (well working) project from Delphi 2006 to XE6.
This project now throws several exception in different Units because of this issue.
What has changed in this regards?

Thank for any help in advance!

Comment: Buttons are ready after the window of the control has been created, it overrides `CreateWnd` to achieve that. Compare the sources of the control in the two Delphi versions to find how that have changed.

Comment: It's typically better not to use `FormCreate` to access controls on a form; use `FormShow` instead, at which point you know that all controls have been properly created.

Comment: @KenWhite It is often OK in `OnCreate` to access controls. They are fully streamed by then. What's dangerous typically is when the access needs windows to have been created.

Comment: @David: I said "typically better", not "always unsafe". If you have no actual need to do so in `OnCreate`, using `OnShow` means you don't have to worry about whether windows have been created, because you know they have been.

Comment: @KenWhite I guess another point is that `OnShow` and `OnCreate` are not always interchangeable. So, `OnShow` can execute multiple times, but `OnCreate` executes exactly once. Can be an apples and oranges scenario.

Comment: @David: Yes, needing the code to only execute once would qualify as an "actual need to do so", I'd think. :-)

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. I ended up moving the code to OnShow, and then only run the code first time OnShow is run (checking with a class level variable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The items are populated when the .dfm file is streamed in. That happens quite early on, certainly well before the `OnCreate` event fires. The buttons, which are windowed controls, are typically created when the window is created. And when the form's `OnCreate` event executes, the window has not been created.

You ask why the items exist, but the buttons do not. Well, the buttons are created from the items. But not immediately. The button creation is suppressed during form streaming, and that means that the items get populated first, and the buttons are created at some point later.

I'm not sure exactly what has changed from the older version of Delphi to the modern Delphi. If you go back to Delphi 6, you can see that the buttons are created in `TCustomRadioGroup.ReadState`, which executes during form streaming. But the latest versions of Delphi suppress the button creation in `ReadState`. My guess as to why this change was made is that it prevents you from setting button properties that get lost during window re-creation.

However, there's probably little point getting in to that in too much detail. The essential fact is that you cannot expect the buttons to exist during `OnCreate`. You should move any code that requires the buttons to exist to a different location. Some obvious candidates would be the form's `OnShow` event, or an overridden `CreateWnd` method.

Comment: A workaround can be to call `HandleNeeded` on the radio group, before accessing buttons. With proper testing...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I think that would be dangerous to do in `OnCreate` though, which is why I did not suggest it

Comment: Maybe, there's probably a reason the implementation has changed.

Comment: Mentioned [here](http://dn.embarcadero.com/article/40204), the first hit on a search for 'TRadioGroup'. No explanation though.. Probably there's a reason..

Comment: It is perfectly safe to access windowed controls in the `OnCreate` event.  Control windows are created on an as-needed basis, and since the DFM has already been streamed, controls have everything they need to create their windows. I frequently initialize window-based properties in the `OnCreate` event in Delphi, and in the form constructor in C++, and it works fine.

Comment: It may lead to an undesired window recreation. Which I suspect is the reason behind the change that is the topic of the question.

Comment: Se my comment under the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: It seems that RadioGroup.ControlCount remains 0 until you access the RadioGroup, so this solution won't work.

After reading this page, I did another search and found this page with a similar problem:
[Problem with RadioGroup.ControlCount in Delphi 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126620/problem-with-radiogroup-controlcount-in-delphi-2010)

It looks like the workaround to avoid throwing exceptions is to check if RadioGroup.ControlCount is greater than the index of the button you want to access.
If RadioGroup.ControlCount is 0, you probably don’t want to access the radio group.

It doesn't really fix the problem of when to initialize it, but it solves the problem of when not to update it.

Dylan